# Reach swift code in static library from Objective-C in main target

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, static-libraries

I want to reach Swift code inside a static library from objective-c code in my main target.

Typically I would have to import the generated `-swift.h` file of the static library in the main target. But the problem is that Xcode generates the `<ProductName>-Swift.h` file in the `/Build` folder under the `/DerivedData` directory, instead of under the regular `/include` directory. Which means it cannot be found by Xcode automatically. Instead the only solution appears to be to copy the `-swift` with a build time copy script to that location.

This works out of the box with a dynamic framework, but I would like to avoid the launch time penalty of adding another dynamic framework if possible.

### Setup ([test project available here](https://github.com/ftronnbe/OperabilityProject))

1. Mixed Objc/Swift main target
2. Mixed Objc/Swift static library

#### Problem

From Objective-C code in the main target, reach swift code in the static library.
The error you get when trying to import the static library is:

[image]
or
[image]

### Attempted solutions

The only solution I've found is to have a **copy phase script** (as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@mail2ashislaha/swift-objective-c-interoperability-static-libraries-modulemap-etc-39caa77ce1fc)) that copies the generated `-swift.h` header of the static library to a location that the main target can find. This appears to me as a not very stable solution as it depends on the inner workings of the where Xcode puts this file at build time. The location also differs when archiving the project.

I've tried to define my own module mapping in the static library (as suggested [here](http://blog.bjhomer.com/2015/05/defining-modules-for-custom-libraries.html)), but didn't manage to get it to work. In the end I the module was still not found by the main target.

Comment: I would tend to treat the library as if it came from a 3rd-party and move it to known library/header locations.  I would then use library and include paths in my main project to find it.  Automatically placing the files correctly could be part of a post-build script in the library project.

Answer (score 1):

**FIX**

I have to apologise - the first attempt I did very hurriedly and not really reading your attempted solutions. Now I had a bit more time and I see you did what I suggest initially. The way to solve Xcode's *inner workings* is to specify a build directory in the preferences. I configured it to `MyBuild` as you can see from the path below. I searched for the file in the `MyBuild` relative dir and used the first one I found. This works no problem but maybe some of the other locations will be better.

```
// This file cannot be found
#import "../../MyBuild/OperabilityProject/Build/Intermediates.noindex/OperabilityProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryOperability.build/DerivedSources/StaticLibraryOperability-Swift.h"
```

**EDIT - using environment variables**

Here is yet another way, this time using environment variables and a little bit of help from https://gist.github.com/gdavis/6670468 . As you can see there, the options are many. I used `BUILD_DIR` but for you also `DERIVED_FILES_DIR` looks interesting.

I included the `BUILD_DIR` into the search path as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Xcode configuration]

Then I was able to reach it in source as below.

```
#include "../Intermediates.noindex/OperabilityProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryOperability.build/DerivedSources/StaticLibraryOperability-Swift.h"
```

As you can see this one works only for `DEBUG` but at least it would be the same for `RELEASE` and I think this is the better alternative, as you can keep the configuration local to the project and not need to edit your (system wide) Xcode configuration as in the first solution option.

Comment: thanks for informative explanation, btw why there are sometimes such differences in Debug and Release modes ?

Comment: @zeytin ... thanks! Depends on what differences you refer to here? But Debug is meant for testing and contain a lot of NSLog's. Release is optimised, strips out debug symbols and should not contain any NSLog's. In my settings I have for Release ```#define NSLog xXxxxXx``` or something ridiculous like that to ensure compile fails if an NSLog ends up in Release. But if you use #ifdef and family correctly you have two different programs rolled up into one. It is easy to maintain as it is a single source file and easy to e.g. log a ton of stuff using NSLog in Debug and this disappear from Release.

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that it relies on where Xcode puts this file. Something that's undocumented. If this is changed then, this stops to work.

Comment: If you use option 1 then *you* define where it is placed. If you use option 2 then if the location changes so does the environment variable so you should be covered.